# Dumping browser document content using Zombie.js

Tags: zombie.js

Using browser.visit, I am fetching the page of a browser as shown in the documentation. According to the browser API, browser.document returns the main window's document. However, I am not sure how to dump (display) the contents of the document. Is there a method like browser.document.toString() or browser.document.text() to be able to print the contents of the document in the console.

Thanks,
Sony

Comment: did you try `browser.html()`?

Comment: Yes, I did. But, it prints the entire html contents, right? I thought browser encompasses all details of the page such as state, content etc. whereas the document is a subset which just stores the dom structure. Am I wrong? I am trying to print just the dom structure using browser.document as against the entire html.

Answer (score 5):

What you want is probably:

```
browser.document.innerHTML
```

Comment: BTW, this doesn't seem to work on the current version of Zombie.js, but `browser.document.documentElement.innerHTML` does ;)

Comment: undefinedundefinedundefinedundefined

Comment: hence the _probably_ keyword :)

Answer (score 3):

There is a `browser.text(selector, context?)`. 
Selector is a CSS selector evaluated against the document body. 
Context is a optional second argument, the CSS selector is evaluated against the element given as the context.

You can say something like `browser.text('body')` to get the text in the body.

Comment: browser.text('document') does not work. I thought document is a selector of browser. I am trying to access the "dom strucuture" via browser.document. - Sony

Comment: @sony browser.text('body') will select whatever text is in the body tag of a html page/document. I haven't tried it but you should be able to do browser.text('html') to select the text in the headers + body.

Answer (score 2):

I got here while looking for answer for the same question.
I may be late for the party, but try using

```
Browser.visit(url, function(error, browser){
    fs.appendFileSync('index.html', browser.html());
})
```

Remember to put error checking here and do better handling, but should give you basic HTML document.

Answer (score 1):

If it's not necessarily HTML (like you find yourself pulling XML or JSON through Zombie due to complicated, valid reasons...), you can access it like this:

```
browser.document._childNodes[0]._nodeValue
```